# Why can we choose a sequence of points uniformly?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure, point-processes

It recently came to my knowledge that, even though there is no way to uniformly choose a random real number (since the Lebesgue measure is not a probability measure), there is a canonical way to choose a random sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the distribution of each point is in some sense uniform (a so-called homogeneous Poisson point process).

I'm not a probabilist, so this looks like dark wizardry to me. Is there a conceptual reason for which "choose a random point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly" has no chance of making any sense, but "choose a random sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly" has a pretty reasonable meaning ?

Comment: The distribution of each point is *in some sense* uniform, so we must specify in which sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Defined_on_the_real_line for the definition of a homogeneous Poisson process on the real line and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Points_are_uniformly_distributed for the explanation of the uniform property.

Comment: Yes, I checked wikipedia before asking my question. But unless I completely misunderstood what is explained there, this is not possible for a random point, because that would mean that there is a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the restriction of $\mu$ to any $[a,b]$ is a multiple of the Lebesgue measure, and that is impossible.

Comment: A neat way to present Poisson processes which escapes the conundrum you seem lost in, is to define a realization of the process as a random *family* of points (with no order, hence not a sequence) such that, for every domain $D$ with finite measure, the number $N_D$ of points of the process in $D$ is finite with Poisson distribution and, conditionally on $N_D=n$, the $n$ points of the process that are in $D$ are i.i.d. uniform in $D$. This way, one uses only probability measures all along.

Comment: Yes, but what seems weird to me is that there is a way to do that for an *infinite* family, but *not* for a finite family, however big it may be (if I made a mistake and this statement is false, then there is my answer). I'm not saying anything seems false, I'm just noticing there is a curious phenomenon that allows you to make uniform choices only for infinite sets, and I'm wondering if there is an intuitive way to understand this behaviour transition.

Comment: "a curious phenomenon that allows you to make uniform choices only for infinite sets" Sorry but I fail to see where such a phenomenon would be even mentioned in my comment. Actually I also fail to understand what you mean here. There is no "uniform choice for infinite sets" involved, *that is the whole point*. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the simple example of a homogeneous Poisson process on $[0,\infty)$ with intensity $\lambda$. 
Think of $[0,\infty)$ as time and the realization of the Poisson process is the sequence of times where a given event occurs: $x_1,x_2,\dots$ Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ the corresponding random variables. So $X_1$ is the time of the first occurence of the event, and so on.

The fact that $N$ is a Poisson process implies that the number of events that occur after time $a$ and before time $b$ is Poisson distributed, with parameter $\lambda (b-a)$. We have
$$N((a,b])\sim\mathcal{P}(\lambda(b-a))$$

Here comes uniformity: given that $N((a,b])=n$ (i.e. there are $n$ occurences of the event in the time interval $(a,b]$), the times of occurence between $a$ and $b$ are uniformly distributed over $(a,b]$. To be more precise, for some $k$, we have $a<X_{k+1}\lt X_{k+2}\lt\dots\lt X_{k+n}\leq b$.

> Then the distribution of $(X_{k+1},\dots,X_{k+n})$ is the same as the distribution of the order statistic $(U_{(1)},\dots,U_{(n)})$ where $U_1,\dots, U_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $(a,b]$.

As this is valid for any interval $(a,b]$, we can say that in some sense, a relaization of $N$ is a random sequence of $[0,\infty)$ chosen uniformly.

---

Another way to explain it:

We denote $N([0,t])$ by $N_t$. Given that $N_t=n$, if you want to simulate the $n$ first times of arrival $X_1,\dots,X_n$, you can just simulate $U_1,\dots,U_n$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, re-order them, and multiply them by $t$.